# Wordpress url rewrite on subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress install which has only two custom post types ( **blog** and **howto** ).

The blog is located in a directory inside root folder where also are few html pages, like this :
[image: root structure]

To access a certain custom post type from html files i have an `href` to **wp/blog** and another one to **wp/howto**.

The problem is that i want to jump that **wp** so my url will be like `localhost/blog` instead `localhost/wp/blog`.

I tried with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   blog/ /wp/blog/
RewriteRule   howto/ /wp/howto/
```

in .htaccess from root directory, it shows me the blog template, but only 404 page error and i have no idea what should i modify to get the wordpress posts.

PS : Sorry for my english and for my blurry message, deadline's coming and i have no idea what should i do to skip that folder.

Comment: Please clarify "I want to jump that wp" - I supposed you mean "skip" (English...). Are you saying that the actual files are at `wp/blog/file.html` but you want it to look like the request is coming from `blog/file.html`? Do you want a link `wp/blog/file.html` to serve up a file that is somewhere else? It would be helpful if you wrote some cases: "When the href is this, I want to serve up page that; when the user types x in the address, I want to give them y". etc. The clearer your requirement, the easier it is to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Actaually what i want is to access these custom posts directly, without having "wp" folder in url, like localhost/blog, instead of localhost/wp/blog. I hope now it's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

1) in your dashboard, go to settings -> general and make sure

a) wordpress directory -> http://mydomain.com/wp

b) site address -> http://mydomain.com

2) move your index.php from subdirectory to the root (MOVE, don't just copy)

3) edit your index.php to read

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp/wp-blog-header.php');
```

where "wp" is your subdirectory

4) delete any .htaccess file in the subdirectory

5) add this to your .htaccess in the root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Under this setup, your wordpress installation will be located in /wp/ directory. Visitors will visit your site using http://mydomain.com.

If you want to have a good read-up on everything so you know exactly what you're doing, read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: I know what you mean. I can't do stuff like this because i won't be able to access the index.html file from root directory, it will automatically shows me the blog. The soultion should be something with rewrite mode.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly - all the wordpress system files are inside the "wp" folder.
if that is the case all you need to do is to drag them out to the main folder and the problem would be fixed by itself.

As far as the post types (blog/howto) if those are post types inside the wordpress system the are not effected by real folders but by something call `Wildcard DNS` - which is a method of linking url's to content by values inside the url. this means that the folder does not have to exist inside the server but just in the system.

For solving your issue i recommend to just, as i said before - drag all the files from inside the folder "wp" - outside of it.

And after that you will need to log in to the database with `phpmyadmin`or any other client you have and go to:

A) choose `wp_options` 
B) Look option_name for `siteurl` and remove the "wp" from the url. `(if it's http://sample.com/wp change it to http://sample.com)` 
C) Look option_name for `home` and do the same.

#### Edit:

Try this:

in your root directory (the parent of "wp"), open the .htaccess file and add inside mod_rewrite.c:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp [L]
```

change the `YourDomain.com` to your real domain.
this should work :)

source: [~here~](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Comment: But if i drag everything outside users won't be able to access the html pages, right? I just want to modify the wordpress url, to be instead of localhost/wp/blog, localhost/blog, without modifying the structure of the folders. I did this, but it does not show me the posts, just 404 error page

Comment: The link was `localhost/wp/...` because the wp is a *static* link, than the wordpress is inside there. what this means is that the root for wordpress is: `localhost/wp/`. what i told you to do is for to change the root folder to the root of the site. have you changed the settings in the database as i told you?

Comment: I can not modify the folders on server. You understand my issue, but I  want to keep the files inside /wp/ but the url should be without "/wp/"

Answer (score -1):

im looking for a solution just like this. People keep on going around the question. What you want is for the custom posts to look like they come from the route mysite.com/todo/have-a-nice-day mysite.com/blog/todo/instead of mysite.com/blog/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33163846)